# How to restrict upload antd to single file?

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
 <Form.Item
    name="upload"
    label="Upload"
    valuePropName="fileList"
    getValueFromEvent={normFile}        
    multiple="false"        
  >
    <Upload accept=".csv" name="logo" multiple="false" action="/upload.do" listType="picture">
      <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to upload</Button>
    </Upload>
  </Form.Item>
```

1. I wan't to allow user to input only one file.
2. Also how to read that csv file after uploading and send to the backend (just the params)?

mutiple files are allowed as below

[image: multiple files]

Comment: are you facing any error in this code. please specify the question

Comment: @sharunkk actually in this case upload allows user to input multiple files, however I want only one file to be allowed

Comment: take a look. https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001=https%3A%2F%2Fant.design%2Fcomponents%2Fupload%2F . no of files uploading is restricted in a different way . you can do it by `fileList = fileList.slice(-1);`or can limit the number of files with condition statement

Comment: @sharunkk can you reshare the link, it's not the correct I guess, thanks

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ihxgf

Answer (score 4):

The solution to your first question is very simple. The Ant Design Upload component API (now?) contains `maxCount`, which limits/controls the number of uploaded files.

Set it to 1 and that will limit the amount of files uploaded to just 1. If a user picks up another file, it will replace the one selected before.

So, you should have something like this in the end:

```
<Form.Item
   name="upload"
   label="Upload"
   valuePropName="fileList"
   getValueFromEvent={normFile}        
   multiple="false">
<Upload 
   accept=".csv" 
   name="logo" 
   multiple="false" 
   action="/upload.do" 
   listType="picture"
   maxCount={1}    //this is what limits the number of files uploaded
>
     <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>
        Click to upload
     </Button>
</Upload>
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I handle this problem by Css, Check my list array length, if true define a className to the upload button which prevent to click.

```
const [list, setList] = useState(null);

<Dragger //its one of antd upload components
  {...settings}
  className={list?.length ? 'blocked' : undefined}
>

.blocked {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maxCount prop is for single file upload.
you check it out.